# vCenter Server power restore

Tags: vmware-vsphere

I am putting together a script and documentation to manage extended power outages for my facility. 
I have a script that automatically shuts down my hardware cleanly.

I also have VMware HA configured on my cluster. Ideally when I power back up the cluster all the VMs should start powering up in the sequence outlined in the HA configuration. Which of the HA options do I need to enable for this behavior? This obviously isn't something I can test freely in production and I don't have a test environment for this kind of thing.

I was originally thinking the virtual machine startup / shutdown options listed under the individual servers would do the trick but those settings apparently are disabled when using a vCenter Server.

EDIT: 
I have the VMware HA Virtual Machine Options set to use the order I would like to use. If my understanding is correct the underlying issue is that the HA functions won't restart a VM that has effectively been manually shut down. I have also included the relevant function of my shutdown script.

```
Function VMWareServer
# This function will shut down all virtual machines and then a VMware environment.
{ param( [string]$Server, [string]$ID, [string]$Password )
Write-Host Connecting to $Server ..
Connect-VIServer $Server -User $ID -Password $Password
Write-Host Getting virtual machines... 
$ESXSRV = Get-VMHost
Foreach ($VM in ($ESXSRV | Get-VM))
{
    Write-Host Shut Down $VM
        If( $shutdown ) 
        { 
            $VM | Shutdown-VMGuest -Confirm:$false 
        }
}
If( $shutdown )
{   # The following lines shut down the remaining VMs and shut down 
    # the VMware servers. 
    Write-Host Waiting for shutdown to complete, be patient
    sleep 30 
    $activeVMs = ($ESXSRV | Get-VM | Where { $_.PowerState -eq "poweredOn" }).Count
    Write-Host Sleepy VMs: $activeVMs
    If( $activeVMs > 0 )
    {
        Write-Host Giving remaining VMs 90 seconds to shut down...
        sleep 90
    }
    $ESXSRV | Foreach {Get-View $_.ID} | Foreach {$_.ShutdownHost_Task($TRUE)}
}
Disconnect-VIServer -Server * -Force -Confirm:$False
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the complexity of this issue I'm going to build out an entire virtual cluster consisting of two ESXi nodes and a vSphere Server. I don't think there is a ready answer to this question without testing. Thanks @SpacemanSpiff and @user48838.

Comment: Have you any updates on this? I was asking similar question but did not solved it.

Comment: A shutdown script as implemented or a client from your ups vendor are the only ways to go I have found. I included the relevant bit of script in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Did you go into the **Properties** (upper right corner) of **Virtual Machine Startup and Shutdown** and checked the **Allow virtual machines to start and stop automatically with the system** check box?

Comment: It works a little differently with an HA setup and a cluster, those settings you referred to above are machine specific. I believe most of what he needs will be in the HA configuration and rules. Say a machine vmotions, if you didn't also set it to startup there, it won't start up.

Comment: My understanding is that all the settings under the virtual machine startup / shutdown screen are overwritten when using the HA option; I can't really test this suggestion. Are you sure it will do what is desired?

Comment: Based upon what SpacemanSpiff pointed out, you should look through the HA settings to determine whether it has similar and/or overriding options.